# How to delete an Angular project

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core

I have the backend of .net core on the API folder and I was trying to put the front on another folder in the same directory. The guy of the tutorial was doing it like that and he was using VS Code instead of Visual Studio.

Something went wrong during the instalation and I ended up with three Angular projects, the fouth is good, it works, so, how can I delete the other three?

[image: This is how the folders are]

Comment: How about just deleting them?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily delete the folder with everything inside.
In the end you are serving the frontend separatedly and hook to the url (localhost:4200)